# Visual Basic Command Line Compiler has stopped working

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, compiler-errors, .net-4.0

Yesterday, I could work with Visual Studio 2010 without any problem. However, today after I turned on the computer and tried to open my project (Web application with Visual Basic.NET) on VS2010 again, I got a message box showing as below:

[image]

Later, I found out after I tried deleting suo file that this message box will show up whenever I open some file in Visual Studio so I tried to run the application. Then, I found another message box popped up as below:

[image]

And after I close the message box, I finally got this window

[image]

It says:
Compilation Error
Compiler Error Message: The compiler failed with error code -1073741511.

I have searched for the solution through the internet. I have found a few methods that might solve the solution such as scanning for virus, using clean boot. I have also tried repairing and uninstalling VS2010 and .NET framework but none still work. Right now, I have no idea what I should to do make it work again.

Anyway, I realized that there is Windows auto update when I turned off the computer. Not so sure if this related to the problem (I used Window 8.1).

Comment: Well, not good, your .NET install got corrupted.  Does not seem like a widely-spread problem, yet, so your .NET version must be a bit unusual, hard to give specific advice.  Do keep in mind that it is actually the one in c:\windows\syswow64 that's the problem.  Uninstalling the update would be the logical workaround.

Comment: @HansPassant I think you're right. It's windows update that cause the problem. I haven't tried your method yet because I have already formatted my drive C and worked all around until everything is back to normal.

However, from spending the whole day reinstalling Windows and necessary program, I have come to a conclusion. I tried installing everything again except all Windows update published after 10 Nov 2015 and that's why I got everything back to normal again.

Comment: It is still very odd, this particular entrypoint doesn't just disappear.  There have been a *lot* of problems with Avast this week.  Make sure you don't put it back on that clean machine.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33721216/why-do-i-get-an-error-for-crtgetfileinformationbyhandleex-when-i-try-to-com

Comment: @HansPassant So the actual cause of this problem is dll version. Thank you so much for the link :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After formatting Drive C to reinstalling everything again, I found out that the reason might be Windows update. I have started from reinstalling Windows 8, all necessary programs (except Visual Studio and SQL Management Studio) and all window updates required for upgrading to Windows 8.1.

When I successfully got to Windows 8.1, I created system restore point and try installing VS2010 and all windows update. The result had caused the same error I posted in this thread.

After that, I restored back to original state and installed VS2010 first. Then installed some of windows updates. This time, I decided to install all updates except the ones that have publish date after 10/11/2015. The result is satisfied. I don't get this error again.

Later, Hans Passant help me find the actual cause of this problem. Please see this link:

[Why do I get an error for "__CrtGetFileInformationByHandleEx " when I try to compile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33721216/why-do-i-get-an-error-for-crtgetfileinformationbyhandleex-when-i-try-to-com)