# Why do I get an error for "__CrtGetFileInformationByHandleEx " when I try to compile

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2015

I just installed Visual Studio 2015 Community on my computer.  Until now I have been using Visual Studio 2010 Professional.  Now when I try to run my MVC apps in the build in web server, I get the following error message.

> The procedure entry point __CrtGetFileInformationByHandleEx could not be located in \WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\msvcp120_clr0400.dll

I get the same error message if I try to execute `vbc.exe` (the Visual Basic compiler) on directly at the command prompt.  My MVC app also shows a YSOD with

> Compilation Error - Compiler Error Message: The compiler failed with error code -1073741511.

How can I fix my VS so I can run my programs again?!

Steps I've tried

1. Uninstall VS 2015 Community
2. Uninstall and reinstall .NET 4.6 and .NET 4.5.2
3. DISM /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth
4. The .NET Repair Tool
5. Run sfc /scannow
6. Manually rename the msvcr120_clr0400.dll file to msvcr120_clr0400.dll.corrupt and do 1-5
7. Uninstall and reinstall VS 2010 w/ SP1

`sfc /scannow` successfully replaced the msvcr120_clr0400.dll file, but it replaced it with *the exact same* CTP file as before!

**EDIT**:

The problem dll's from my system are available for download here:

- [32 bit](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-8KxWa-iE2Tdmt1X04xV2ZqY2c/view?usp=sharing)
- [64 bit](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-8KxWa-iE2TdFZlUm8yOE5pSWM/view?usp=sharing)
- [32 bit msvcr](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-8KxWa-iE2TajF1Z0xuSkk5Rmc/view?usp=sharing)
- [64 bit msvcr](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-8KxWa-iE2TT0pLQi1NYUMteE0/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Try a repair install.

Comment: @SLaks of which one, VS 2010 or VS 2015? Or both?

Comment: You are the third SO user to have this bizarre problem this week.  It has been raining all week, and where the rain is coming from isn't always obvious because nobody says what exactly happened with their machine.  Not likely to be a Windows update, there are not enough complaints about it.  But there are *many* about a very common scourge on programmers' machines and particularly troublesome this week, you need to uninstall Avast if you use that horrid virus.

Comment: @SLaks I just ran the repair install.  I still get the exact same error.

Comment: Btw, do everybody a favor and copy c:\windows\syswow64\msvcp120_clr0400.dll to a file sharing service so we can see for ourselves.  Post the link to the share in your question.

Comment: @HansPassant I added the links to the question.

Comment: Thanks, the file is good.  Could you also please upload c:\windows\syswow64\msvcr120_clr0400.dll.  Note the "r" instead of the "p".

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Microsoft is aware of this issue with KB3098779 and 3097997:

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3118750

The recommendation is to uninstall these patches and then rescan for updates.  Newer versions of these security patches (that do not break the VB compiler) are now available.

Answer (score 3):

Okay, I see it from the files you uploaded to the sharing service, your .NET install is corrupted.  A standard DLL Hell problem, your c:\windows\syswow64\msvcr120_clr400.dll file is the wrong version.  Something you can see when you use Explorer and navigate to the file.  Right-click and select Properties, look at the Details tab.

[image]

Note the word "CTP" in the Product name, means "Community Technology Preview". A Microsoft term that means "beta version".  Clearly you should not be having the VS2013 beta on your machine.  Your msvcp120_clr0400.dll is correct, it is file version 12.0.52512.0.  It depends on an exported function in the msvcr DLL that the CTP version did not yet have.

Exactly how this happened is always hard to reverse-engineer.  You are the 3rd SO user that I know of that had this problem this week, a bit too much of a coincidence.  Two basic scenarios, if you ever had the VS2013 CTP edition installed on the machine then the problem is that it didn't get updated like it should have.  Otherwise a very typical problem with CTP editions, they are pretty dangerous because the uninstaller is always the last thing Microsoft gets right.  And the problem was just never detected until you started using a program that required this export.

Or it was caused by a rogue installer, copying the old version onto your machine without checking the version number.  Much less likely, installers never have a good reason to install this particular file since it is only ever used by the .NET Framework.  My money is therefore on your machine getting corrupted by the CTP.

You need to solve this by getting your machine fixed.  Not that easy, you can never be sure how many other bad DLLs are lying around from such a bad CTP uninstall.  A shortcut is copying this particular DLL from a good machine.  But best to get .NET 4.6 re-installed.

EDIT from OP:

This answer correctly identified the problem files but reinstalling (or any other common steps) didn't solve it.  In the end I copied "good" files from another computer with the version number 12.0.20806.33440.

Comment: The product name on that file is numbered VS 12 which AFAIK is the version number of Visual Studio 2015.  I just installed the community preview right before this error started, so I'm guessing that's the culprit.  I'll uninstall and see what happens.

Comment: No, VS2015 is version number 14.  As noted in the answer, don't use "community preview" versions, CTPs are betas and are not supposed to work correctly.  Getting them to mess up your machine is another bonus.

Comment: I've never used any CTP software on my machine.  I don't know how it got on there.

Comment: Then what does "I just installed the community preview" mean?

Comment: I just installed Visual Studio 2015 *Community*.  That's the new edition of VS that Microsoft created starting with 2015.  It's similar to the Express version they have offered in the past.

Comment: Careful with the word "preview".  As noted in the answer, this could have gone wrong a long time ago, what you did 3 years ago can be hard to remember today :)  Well, just clean it up.  Good luck, please close your question.

Comment: I just completely uninstalled and reinstalled .NET 4.6.  It did not help.  It seems like my .NET 4.0 is messed up.  I'm running Windows 8.1.  I don't know how to remove/reinstall .NET 4.0.

Comment: It is important that you delete this file yourself, before you start the installer again.  So the installer can write a "fresh" copy.  You might then also discover why the installer could not overwrite the file in the first place.

Comment: Please see updated steps tried in my question.  I renamed the original msvcr file and uninstalled/reinstalled .NET 4.6.  No effect.  I ran sfc /scannow and it recreated the CTP version of the file.

Comment: I finally manually copied the problem files from my wife's computer.  They also say CTP in the properties, but they have a different version number.  The problem is now solved.  I'm marking this as the answer and adding adding a note of the file version number which solved it for me.

Answer (score 3):

KB3098779 appears to be the culprit on our server.  That is the patch that installed the rogue CTP msvcr120_clr0400.dll mentioned in the above answer.
**Solution**: we reversed out the patch set that applied KB3098779, and everything is working again.
FYI: this is a .NET framework 4+ issue, not Visual Studio.  Our server is a standard 2012 IIS server: Visual Studio is not installed.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue on Windows 8.1 although KB3098779 and 3097997 were not installed on my machine. Probably it happened after installation of ASP.Net 5.

The issue was that I had both mcvcr files in version 12.0.51670.34230 while mcvcp files were already in 12.00.52512.0. It was enough to copy both mcvcr files (from System32 and SysWOW64) in this version from my colleague's pc.

If you have problems with permissions set to TrustedInstaller on these file, you can run this powershell command and then change permissions as Administrator:

```
takeown /A /F C:\windows\syswow64\msvcr120_clr0400.dll
```

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft have issued a notice on this.
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3118750

As others have pointed out too many people in too short a time to be a coincidence. Not a VS issue, this is to do with a bad update from Microsoft.

The info from MS mentions two security patches (KB3098779 and KB3097997).

I have uninstalled only KB3098779 and my site is up was up and running. It required a machine restart to complete

KB3097997 uninstalled without a restart. I maybe didn't need to uninstall but seems sensible given it is also subject to the same notice from MS.