# Visual Basic Command Line Compiler has stopped working.I cannot compile my project

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

I am working with visual studio 2010. Its working fine but now showing this popup "Visual Basic Command Line Compiler has stopped working" . I have scanned malware with 'Malwarebytes' & reinstalled visual studio but still facing this problem. I cannot compile my project. I have installed Visual Studio 2015 Community , Its could be any problem ?

[image]

After Click on Debug I am getting this message:

An unhandled win32 exception occurred in vbc.exe The Just-In-Time debugger was launched without necessary security permissions. To debug this process, the Just-In-Time debugger must be run as an Administrator. Would you like to debug this process? Process Name: C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\vbc.exe

Thank you for your help in advance !!

Comment: You need to click the Debug button to find out why it bombed.  Not an unusual problem this week btw, the canonical Q+A [is here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33721216/why-do-i-get-an-error-for-crtgetfileinformationbyhandleex-when-i-try-to-com).

Comment: Click on Debug: An unhandled win32 exception occurred in vbc.exe 

The Just-In-Time debugger was launched without necessary security permissions. To debug this process, the Just-In-Time debugger must be run as an Administrator. Would you like to debug this process?

Process Name: C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\vbc.exe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have updated windows 8.1 to windows 10. Now my issue is resolved.I tried lot of things & wasted 2 days with this issue but couldn't solve this. After that i updated my windows. I didn't find out what was the actual issue.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone having this issue, this Microsoft knowledge base entry solved the issue for me:

> [Known issue for security updates 3098779 and 3097997 for the .NET Framework 4.5.1 and 4.5.2 after you install the .NET Framework 4.6 on Windows 8.1, Windows RT 8.1, and Windows Server 2012 R2](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3118750)