# IIf function doesn't work (Visual Studio 2013 BI Tools)

Tags: visual-studio-2013, reporting-services, sql-server-2014, bi-tool

I'm using Visual Studio 2013 (with SQL-Server 2014, Reporting Services and BI Tools) and I try to add an simple "iif" expression but the compiler returns an Error (value = -1073741511)

I tried:

```
= IIf ( 3000 > 1000, "True", "False" )
```

Is it possible that the compiler doesn't support these kind of expression or are there similar ones?

What I need is an expression to get a value from my db where the id = x

```
= IIf ( Fields!ID.Value = 1 , Fields!Value.Value, 0 )
```

[image]

Comment: Have you tried    = IIf ( Fields!ID.Value = 1 , Fields!ID.Value, 0 )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a problem with the compiler itself

See this post for more infos: [Visual Basic Command Line Compiler has stopped working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33670196/visual-basic-command-line-compiler-has-stopped-working)

anyway thanks!