# Preview of SSRS Report fails in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012, reporting-services, report, ssrs-2012

My SSRS report does not compile on my computer. But it does compile on the computer of a friend.
I have done extensive Google research on this issue to no avail.
The preview *does* work when there are no parameters but when added it breaks.

I have also uninstalled and reinstalled Visual Studio 2012 and updated it...still doesn't work.

Does anyone know the requirements for SSRS or the reasons this issue would happen?  Any help on this issue would be much appreciated!

Keep in mind that it works on my friends computer just fine.

[image: Error Message]

Comment: Very unclear question but [check this duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33670196/visual-basic-command-line-compiler-has-stopped-working) and follow the advice in [this accepted answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33721216/why-do-i-get-an-error-for-crtgetfileinformationbyhandleex-when-i-try-to-com)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I have edited your question; made the title more specific and re-arranged the contents, hopefully making it more clear. If you have logs from Visual Studio, you could edit them in... it _might_ just help someone spot the problem.